# Diamond hotend with single extruder motor

Tags: fdm, multi-material, diamond-hotend

Today I started to google the idea of multimaterial printing. I checked out prusa multimaterial upgrade and while it looks nice, it is expensive and will not probably work with my non-prusa printer.

I discovered there is Diamond hotend, which allows for 3 (or even more) colors at the same time. But everywhere I checked, one extruder motor was used for each color. Since my MKS Gen L motor connections are already all used, I was thinking if it would be possible to handle all of the filaments with single extruder motor.

Basically the motor would have long shaft which will cover all filaments, and I would add some servo that would push a pulley against the selected filament.

I think I would slice it as a multiple hotend setup and then postprocess the gcode in a way, that when tool is changed I would add custom command that would push the pulley against appropriate filament.

I would either need a servo for each of the filemants, or maybe with some clever mechanics one servo in different positions could do all of them.

I am just curious if you think this would be possible to do, since I did not find anyone discussing this idea. Probably because it will require adding custom commands to the firmware.

Comment: Sounds a lot like the MMU concept - which *is* available online for you to build yourself.

As for the diamond hotend and your board, it might be easier to have a look at the Klipper firmware and just use two boards.

Comment: I did not find any information about how to make the MMU, just $300 to buy it.

Comment: what you describe is a variant of the Prusa MMU2 but with triple the bowden tubes and a hotend about 2-4 times as heavy.

Answer (score 2):

You might save yourself a lot of engineering by copying the Prusa MMU2.  Here is a github project for someone doing exactly that:  https://github.com/cskozlowski/mmu2

If you look on [Prusa's web site, you can find printable parts for the MMU2](https://www.prusa3d.com/prusa-i3-printable-parts/).

Comment: I also noticed that new version of Marlin includes the support for the prusa MMU2, so maybe this is the way to go... except I still have to solve how to control the additional motors....